# Error in source folder generation on using schematic library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I get the following message on building the project. I guess the problem is due to using this repo https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic but i'm unable to correct it.

```
Warning:Folder /home/priyanshu/AndroidStudioProjects/Ud Courses/AdvancedAndroid_Squawker-TFCM.00-StartingCode/app/build/source/apt/debug
Information:3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause
```

Also in my AndroidMenifest.xml the studio is unable to recognize `android:name=".provider.generated.SquawkProvider"` the warning message is this -

```
Unresolved package 'generated' less  
Validates resource references inside Android XML files
```

This is my AndroidMenifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.example.com.squawker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="fcm.SquawkMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".fcm.SquawkFirebaseInstanceService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name=".provider.generated.SquawkProvider"
            android:authorities="android.example.com.squawker.provider.provider"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".following.FollowingPreferenceActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my build.gradle file( module :app) -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com.squawker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // RecyclerView

    // Schematic dependencies for ContentProvider

    // Preferences Dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a workaround for this issue.

On app/build.gradle use Schematic version "0.7.0".

```
apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.7.0'
compile 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.7.0'
```

and on the end of file add:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'build/source/apt/{buildType}'
}
```

I tested this on Android Studio 3.0 and Gradle 4.1.

---

If you have an error with apt, you may need to add on your app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

and on build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
}
```